# Terminal output looking weird

Tags: terminal, macos, iterm2

I just got a new macOS system, and the output text in the terminal is not properly formatted.

Every line is indented every time a newline is printed, instead of "on top" of each other so it ends up looking like a waterfall of words.

I am using iTerm2.

This happens no matter which shell I use.

Anyone know what I can do to fix this?

[image: Terminal looking weird]

Answer (score 1):

Usual Unix programs send only a LF character at the end of the line, but terminals needs CR and LF. Then the system (the kernel) should convert LF to CR LF. Some programs disable this conversion in order to control better the terminal interaction but should restore the default mode before ending.

To restore the default mode, type `stty sane`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer but this didnt fix the problem.